# What does this string do in a Unity lens?

Tags: application-development, lenses

My question is based on [this article](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/04/how-to-create-a-wikipedia-unity-lens-for-ubuntu/).

My Wikipedia lens is working well and this article is very nice.
But I don't understand, what is this string doing:

```
for article in self.wikipedia_query(search):
```

I want to link my Lens with Google AJAX Search API, but my code is don't working.

Answer (score 3):

You have a basic understanding of Python, right?

It's a basic for-loop which iterates over the return value of the `wikipedia_query()` method and stores it as `article` for each iteration.
Same as each simple loop, like:

```
for x in range(4):
    print x
```